# Continuous state in Apache Beam pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm developing a beam pipeline for dataflow runner. I need the below functionality in my use case.

1. Read input events from Kafka topic(s). Each Kafka message value derives `[userID, Event]` pair.
2. For each `userID`, I need to maintain a `profile` and based on the current `Event`, a possible update to the `profile` is possible. If the `profile` is updated:

   - Updated `profile` is written to output stream.
   - The next `Event` for that `userID` in the pipeline should refer to the updated profile.

I was thinking of using the provided state functionality in Beam, without depending on an external key-value store for maintaining the user profile. Is this feasible with the current version of beam (`2.1.0`) and `dataflow` runner? If I understand correctly the state is scoped to the elements in a single window firing (i.e even for a `GlobalWindow`, the state will be scoped to the elements in a single firing of the window caused by a trigger). Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

State would be perfectly appropriate for your use case.

The only correction is that state is scoped to a single window, but trigger firings do not affect it. So, if your state is small you can store it in a global window. When a new element arrives, you can use use the state, output elements as needed, and make changes to the state.

The only thing to consider would be if you have an unbounded number of user IDs, how big the state may become. For instance, you may want an inactivity timer to clear old user state after some period of time.

If you haven't read them, the blog posts [Stateful Processing with Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html) and [Timely (and Stateful) Processing with Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html) provide a good introduction to these concepts and APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As state is per window, and not window firing, it is definitely useful. So a global window (or a fixed time window of longer duration) with a trigger followed by `GroupByKey`  on userID will guarantee that the records for a userID will be delivered to the same worker where the user state is held. A (`setRelative` with `offset`) inactivity timer used in a stateful DoFn already handles timer per key and window. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Basically -- but it's even easier. The use of a a Stateful DoFn is already per key, so you don't need to use the GroupBykey before the state, and you also don't need to use a trigger. Just set a window for how long you want the state to be retained, then do a Stateful DoFn using the User ID as a key.

Comment: Cool! This is really helpful as `GroupByKey` is quite expensive in dataflow. The trigger still makes sense when we need to get something out of the window before it expires. In each window firing, state will be updated and the next firing will refer to the updated state.

Comment: The trigger won't affect the stateful DoFn. Your Stateful DoFn will output either on the arrival of input elements (in processElement) or when a timer it sets fires (in processTimer). Triggering is only necessary if you have additional aggregations *after* the DoFn.