# Persisting index map in Apache Beam pipeline on Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm designing a pipeline with the following functionality:

1. Read Events from different Pub/Sub topics providing me with objects from which I can extract a `StrId` (String)
2. Load a mapping table from Bigtable with `KV(StrId, IntId>` where `IntId` is a unique integer
3. Look up the `StrId` in that mapping:

   - If `StrId` is found, return corresponding `IntId`
   - If `StrId` is not found, generate a new `IntId` sequentially, add it to the mapping and also write it to Bigtable
4. Pass the object and `IntId` downstream

I'm wondering whether the state approach would fit my needs here, and whether Bigtable is the right storage technology to use? The mapping between `StrId` and `IntId` would have to be persisted across all workers in order to keep `IntIds` unique.

Also, any links to code examples would be greatly appreciated. I'm aware of this [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206265/continuous-state-in-apache-beam-pipeline) and this [blog post](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html).

(For the downstream calculations, I need integer Ids, so there's no way around that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds very much like what [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net/) does to manage strings in its tsdb-uid table.  That process requires a combination of increment (aka ReadModifyWrite) to get a unique id (which is an int64 / long), and a CheckAndMutate to ensure that you only have one unique mapping.  It's a more difficult process than what you get out of SQL systems.

That said, Cloud Bigtable is not ideal for managing small tables like the uid table (i.e. less than a couple of GB).  If you're using Cloud Bigtable to store lots of data, you can consider using Cloud Bigtable for the uid table as well.  However, I would still suggest also looking at a SQL alternative for that functionality.