# Is it possible to get the state of the previous window for a given key

Tags: apache-beam, dataflow

I have events (ProductOrderRequested, ProductColorChanged, ProductDelivered...) and I want to build a golden record of my product.

But my goal is to build the golden record step by step : each session of activity will give me an updated state of my product and I need to store each version of the state for tracability purpose

I have a quite simple pipeline (code is better than words) :

```
events
 .apply("SessionWindow", Window.
          <KV<String, Event>>into(Sessions.withGapDuration(gapSession)
          .triggering(<early and late data trigger>))
 .apply("GroupByKey", GroupByKey.create())
 .apply("ComputeState", ParDo.of(new StatefulFn()))
```

My problem is for a given window I have to compute the new state based on :

1. The previous state (i.e computed state of the previous window)
2. The events received

I would like to avoid calling an external service to get the previous state but instead get the state of the previous window. Is it something possible ?

Answer (score 2):

In Apache Beam state is always scoped per window (also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206265/continuous-state-in-apache-beam-pipeline?rq=1)). So I can only think of re-windowing into the global window and handle the state there. In this global `StatefulFn` you can store and handle the prior state(s).

It would then look like this:

```
events
 .apply("SessionWindow", Window.
          <KV<String, Event>>into(Sessions.withGapDuration(gapSession)
          .triggering(<early and late data trigger>))
 .apply("GroupByKey", GroupByKey.create())
 .apply("Re-window into Global Window", Window.
          <KV<String, Event>>into(new GlobalWindows())
          .triggering(<early and late data trigger>))
 .apply("ComputeState", ParDo.of(new StatefulFn()))
```

Please also note that as of now, Apache Beam doesn't support stateful processing for merging windows (see this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2507)). Therefore, your `StatefulFn` on a session window basis will not work properly when your triggers emit early or late results of session windows since the state is not merged. This is another reason to work with a non-merging window like the global window.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean, that for an "infinitely" running pipeline, the state will grow only grow in size and will never be garbage collected?

Comment: Actually you can clear the [state](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.8.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/state/State.html). In a case as described above you'll likely use [timers](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.8.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/state/Timer.html) to trigger it.